# nodejs pm2 Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm new to NodeJS development.

I've set up Ubuntu 14.04 as a guest OS through VirtualBox on a host Windows machine.  When I type into Ubuntu `ifconfig`, I get the ip address `192.168.8.101`.  I also added an entry to my Windows host file so that `jl.gamatrix.com` points to that address.  I checked out a git project onto the ubuntu machine, set up node js and pm2 and nginx.

When I type

`pm2 deploy ecosystem.json5 jlgamatrix`

I get the output

```
{
--> Deploying to jlgamatrix environment
--> on host jl.gamatrix.com
fatal: No upstream configured for branch 'master'
  ○ deploying origin/master
  ○ executing pre-deploy-local
  ○ hook pre-deploy
  ○ fetching updates
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '125.211.213.131' to the list of known hosts.
Password:
Password:
Password:
Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive).

  fetch failed
```

Where each time it asked for a password, I entered in the correct password.  Why do I keep getting a permission denied?  Especially since `git pull origin master` and `git push origin master` on their own via bash don't experience any issues?

Here's what my `ecosystem.json5` file looks like:

```
  apps : [

    // First application
    {
      name      : "gamatrix",
      script    : "/usr/local/bin/grunt",
      env: {
        COMMON_VARIABLE: "true"
      },
      env_production : {
        NODE_ENV: "production"
      }
    },

  ],

  deploy : {
    production : {
      user : "emd",
      host : "someserver.com",
      ref  : "origin/master",
      repo : "bb_gamatrix_deploy:emd/meanjs-gamatrix.git",
      path : "/home/emd/gamatrix-prod/",
      "post-deploy" : "npm install && bower install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json5 --env production"
    },
    jlgamatrix : {
      user : "www-data",
      host : "jl.gamatrix.com",
      ref  : "origin/master",
      repo : "bb_gamatrix_deploy:eemd/meanjs-gamatrix.git",
      path : "/var/www/nginx/gamatrix",
      "post-deploy" : "npm install && bower install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json5 --env dev",
      env  : {
        NODE_ENV: "jlgamatrix"
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set permissions to your files (chmod -x):

```
production : {
      user : "emd",
      host : "someserver.com",
      ref  : "origin/master",
      repo : "bb_gamatrix_deploy:emd/meanjs-gamatrix.git",
      path : "/home/emd/gamatrix-prod/",
      pre-deploy: "npm install",
      post-deploy : "chmod -x ecosystem.json && bower install && pm2      startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env production"
    }
```